# MIT Java WordNet Interface: Exception in thread "main" edu.mit.jwi.data.IHasLifecycle$ObjectClosedException

Tags: java, eclipse, jwi

I use JWI in Eclipse to access WordNet on Mac. I followed the example:

```
package tutorial;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import edu.mit.jwi.*;
import edu.mit.jwi.item.IIndexWord;
import edu.mit.jwi.item.IWord;
import edu.mit.jwi.item.IWordID;
import edu.mit.jwi.item.POS;

public class ExampleWordnet {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    //construct URL to WordNet Dictionary directory on the computer
    String wordNetDirectory = "/Users/Laura/Documents/WordNet-3.0";
    //String path = wordNetDirectory + File.separator + "dict";
    URL url = new URL("file", null, wordNetDirectory);


    //construct the Dictionary object and open it
    IDictionary dict = new Dictionary(url);
    dict.open();

    // look up first sense of the word "dog "
    IIndexWord idxWord = dict.getIndexWord ("dog", POS.NOUN );
    IWordID wordID = idxWord.getWordIDs().get(0) ;
    IWord word = dict.getWord (wordID);         
    System.out.println("Id = " + wordID);
    System.out.println(" Lemma = " + word.getLemma());
    System.out.println(" Gloss = " + word.getSynset().getGloss());      
}    }
```

But I cannot run it. There are always errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" edu.mit.jwi.data.IHasLifecycle$ObjectClosedException
at edu.mit.jwi.CachingDictionary.checkOpen(CachingDictionary.java:111)
at edu.mit.jwi.CachingDictionary.getIndexWord(CachingDictionary.java:172)
at tutorial.ExampleWordnet.main(ExampleWordnet.java:28)
```

Could anybody please help me?

Comment: It seems to be suggesting that the dict object is still in a Closed state. You are calling open just above it, maybe check if you've constructed the object correctly?

Comment: Which is line 28? Is it the one with `dict.getWord`?

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved. I wrongly write the url.

Comment: could you post the solution?